# Android menu definitions explaination

Tags: android, menu, contextmenu, submenu, optionmenu

What are the differences between the following types of menus in Android?

1. option menu
2. context menu
3. sub menu

Can anyone give me an explanation and an example for each?

Comment: Can you please explain, why you moved the accepted mark from my answer to the one from Mojo? And why after a half year? Just curious..

Answer (score 4):

1. Option menu: The menu that appears when you press the menu button
2. Context menu: The menu that appears like a dialog with a list when you (mostly) longpress on list elements
3. Sub menu: can be used to display more menu items with your option menu.

More details: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html